# how to remove red lines from a text in editText and prevent and editTextView from expanding after pressing enter in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

how do i remove the red lines and also prevent the editText view from expanding after pressing enter.

here's the image link:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove spellcheck (red lines) use

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

and tomake edittext supporting single line please use

```
android:maxLines="1"
```

Comment: maxLines="1" is deprecated, use singleLine="true" instead

Comment: @borune Isn't it reverse? `singleLine=true` is deprecated not `maxLines`.

Comment: Do you know how to fix this error? Failed to resolve: info.hoang8f.fbutton:1.0.5: